# How to determine when a file is updated in c++?

Tags: c++, file, timestamp

I am using an application which takes File X as input and gives File Y and Z as output (graphs and plots)
Now if the applicatoin is run again :

1. File Y and Z already exists and File X is not updated then it should not be over-written.
2. File X is updated, then File Y and Z must be overwritten.

The code is written in c++, how can i change the code such that both the conditions are met? Should I take time stamp of X everytime?

Comment: Sounds like you're rewriting `make` :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a POSIX machine, use `stat` or a related function such as `fstat`. The windows equivalents are described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff(v=vs.80).aspx.

The structure returned by `stat` or the windows counterparts have a field that represents the time at which the file was last modified.

Answer (score 1):

For a portable solution, Boost.Filesystem has [last_write_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#last_write_time) that returns the time of last modification as a `std::time_t`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep a hash of file X. If the has changes, the file has been changed (updated), and you will need to update Y and Z.

```
if (XHashPrev != XHashNow || !YZExist)
    // update files.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should inspect the file X and see (two options):

- if its update date changed or
- or if its content changed (using a CRC32 as an example).

The first is the easiest and the fastest. The second is the most accurate. 
*EDIT further to the comments below:* These two options can be combined to reach a compromise.

Comment: I would suggest doing both - if the date has changed, perform a hash verification of the file content. It's possible that the content won't have changed even tho' the date has.

Comment: That's a good idea. This is a good compromise between resources consumption (checking dates is quicker than always calculating CRC32) and accuracy (when the date changed, we check whether the content is actually different). This would be less accurate than only relying on the CRC if for some reason the date was reset after a content change, but this sounds acceptable. Actually, the operator between these two options is a OR, not a XOR :)

Answer (score 0):

using David Hammen's answer, compare modification timestamp of X against Y and Z, if X was modified later than Y or Z - so they are outdated and should be rewritten

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: write the basic program with X always overwriting Y and Z. Invoke the basic program with make. A makefile that looks like:

```
Y Z : X
    basicProgram X Y Z
```

should do the trick. You can then invoke it with either "make Y" or "make Z"
Bottom line: let make worry about timestamps and such.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when checking for last update time, there are [some limitations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/filesystem/doc/operations.htm#last_write_time):

> ... The [time] resolution is as low as one hour on some filesystems... During program execution, the system clock may be set to a new value by some other, possibly automatic, process ...